# How to change the group, excluding a directory

Tags: linux, permissions, file-permissions

We are using AWS S3 Buckets, and when you attempt to do a recursive `chgrp`, it churns on the S3 bucket (essentially) indefinitely.  Is it possible to execute `chgrp` while excluding a directory?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use GNU `find`'s ability to not follow a directory path into another filesystem:

```
find /some/path -mount -exec chgrp groupname {} +
```

Comment: Does this execute recursively?

Comment: @Mike yes, it is recursive.

Answer (score 2):

The answer is the use of bash `extglob`, and works here, as well as many other Linux functions that accept file designation in the `/directory/*` form.

Changing the group of files greedily in a directory, while excluding a directory, is possible by first turning `extglob` on, and then including the directory name to exclude as such:

```
shopt -s extglob
chgrp /directory/!(exclude)
```

And when you are done, turn the option off with the `-u` flag.

```
shopt -u extglob
```

For a helpful Stack post on it, look at "[How can I use inverse or negative wildcards when pattern matching in a unix/linux shell?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/217208/1301994)"